# Converting an `Option[A]` to an Ok() or NotFound() inside an Http4s API

Tags: scala, scala-cats, http4s, tagless-final

I've got an API that looks like this:

```scala
object Comics {
  ...

  def impl[F[_]: Applicative]: Comics[F] = new Comics[F] {
    def getAuthor(slug: Authors.Slug): F[Option[Authors.Author]] =
      ...
```

and a routing that looks like this:

```scala
object Routes {
  def comicsRoutes[F[_]: Sync](comics: Comics[F]): HttpRoutes[F] = {
    val dsl = new Http4sDsl[F] {}
    import dsl._
    HttpRoutes.of[F] {
      case GET -> Root / "comics" / authorSlug =>
        comics
          .getAuthor(Authors.Slug(authorSlug))
          .flatMap {
            case Some(author) => Ok(author)
            case None         => NotFound()
          }
```

So when there is a `None`, it gets converted to a 404. Since there are several routes, the `.flatMap { ... }` gets duplicated.

**Question:** How do I move this into a separate `.orNotFound` helper function specific to my project?

---

My attempt:

To make things simple for me (and avoid parameterisation over `F` initially), I've tried to define this inside `comicsRoutes`:

```scala
  def comicsRoutes[F[_]: Sync](comics: Comics[F]): HttpRoutes[F] = {
    val dsl = new Http4sDsl[F] {}
    import dsl._

    def orNotFound[A](opt: Option[A]): ???[A] =
      opt match {
        case Some(value) => Ok(value)
        case None        => NotFound()
      }

    HttpRoutes.of[F] {
      case GET -> Root / "comics" / authorSlug =>
        comics
          .getAuthor(Authors.Slug(authorSlug))
          .flatMap(orNotFound)
```

But what's `???` here? It doesn't seem to be `Response` or `Status`. Also, the `.flatMap { ... }` was made under `import dsl._`, but I'd like to move this further out. What would a good place be? Does it go into the routes file, or do I put it in a [separate `ExtendedSomething` extension file](https://coderwall.com/p/4clu3a/extension-methods-in-scala)? (I expect that `???` and `Something` might be related, but I'm a little confused as to what the missing types are.)

(Equally importantly, how do I find out what `???` is here? I was hoping `???` at the type level might give me a "typed hole", and VSCode's hover function provides very sporadic documentation value.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type returned by `Http4sDsl[F]` for your actions is `F[Response[F]]`.

It has to be wrapped with `F` because your are using `.flatMap` on `F`. `Response` is parametrized with `F` because it will produce the result returned to caller using `F`.

To find that out you can use IntelliJ and then generate the annotation by IDE (Alt+Enter and then "Add type annotation to value definition"). You can also:

- preview implicits to check that `Ok` object imported from `Statuses` trait is provided extension methods with `http4sOkSyntax` implicit conversion (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Plus sign, you can press it a few times to expand implicits more, and Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Minut to hide them again)
- find `http4sOkSyntax` by pressing Shift twice to open find window, and then pressing it twice again to include non-project symbols,
- from there navigate with Ctrl+B through `OkOps` to `EntityResponseGenerator` class which is providing you the
  functionality you used (in `apply`) returning `F[Resposne[F]]`.

So if you want to move things around/extract them, pay attention to what implicits are required to instantiate the DSL and extension methods.

(Shortcuts differ between Mac OS - which sometime use Cmd instead of Ctrl - and non-Mac OS systems so just check them in documentation if you have an issue).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mateusz, I learned that `???` should be `F[Response[F]]`.

To make this helper function work fully, two more type-related problems occurred:

1. Since `value: A` is polymorphic, Http4s expects an implicit  `EntityEncoder[F, A]` in order to serialize an arbitrary value. (This was not a problem with the original `{ case ... }` match, since the type was concrete and not polymorphic.
2. Adding this implicit annotation was, for some reason, not enough. Doing `.flatMap(orNotFound)` fails type inference. Doing `.flatMap(orNotFound[Authors.Slug])` fixes this.

(Thanks to keynmol for pointing out the other two.)

Having all three changes, this results in:

```scala
  def comicsRoutes[F[_]: Sync](comics: Comics[F]): HttpRoutes[F] = {
    val dsl = new Http4sDsl[F] {}
    import dsl._

    def orNotFound[A](opt: Option[A])(implicit ee: EntityEncoder[F, A]): F[Response[F]] =
      opt match {
        case Some(value) => Ok(value)
        case None        => NotFound()
      }

    HttpRoutes.of[F] {
      case GET -> Root / "comics" / authorSlug =>
        comics
          .getAuthor(Authors.Slug(authorSlug))
          .flatMap(orNotFound[Authors.Author])
      ...
```

Comment: `orNotFound` is parametric and has two parameter lists so you cannot just pass it as `orNotFound`. Either do what you did or `orNotFound(_)`. Then Scala will know that it needs to fill the first parameter list using what `flatMap` provides and will infer the type of implicit that it could take in eta expansion into function.